# meaning of get in got much less wear

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I am not sure of the meaning of:

> Rugs in the bedrooms got much less wear.

A sentence I read from a dictionary
[Entry 5](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wear)

According to the sentence above,

**could we say we can clean rugs in the bedrooms more easily?**

**Because rugs in the living room got much more wear,**

**We have to spend more time cleaning rugs in the living room.**

Comment: *wear* doesn't refer to need for cleaning. It is about deterioration due to use. Bedroom rugs don't usually have people walking back and forth on them a lot, like rugs in other parts of a house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get* means *are subjected to.* Bedroom rugs wear out more slowly than those in parts of the house where people walk about in the daytime. From your comments I assume the sentence must follow one which refers to rugs in the living room.

Comment: I added the source of this sentence. It is from a dictionary. No context of previous sentence at all. I just guess that so I can try to figure out the puzzle I have.

Answer (score 0):

By saying the rugs in the bedrook has less wear, it does not mean the living room rug has more wear. Although the use of "less" implies a comparison with rugs in another part of the house, presumably mentioned in a previous sentence.

Comment: The sentence _implies_ a comparison with rugs in another part of the house, presumably mentioned in a previous sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting is my answer accurate now?

Comment: You say "It does not mean that the living room rug has more wear", but 'less' _does_ mean that floor coverings in some unspecified place get more wear.